# Issue finding specific div with same class - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file selector that populates a div with a thumbnail based on the file.  Now I have multiple buttons and divs that contain the same class names.  What I am using for each time the primary button is selected is, `var thisButton = $(event.target);` which translates to:

```
var appendThis = thisButton.closest('.insurance').find(".attachmentCont");
            appendThis.append('<div class="singleImg"><img src="'+attachment.url+'" width="100px"/><input type="hidden" class="fileURL" value="'+attachment.id+'"/><span class="removeImg remove"> X </span></div>');
            $(".removeImg").bind('click', function(){
               $(this).parent().remove(); 
            });
```

The `appenThis` equals the button which is within a div containing another div `attachmentCont` Both the button and div are within a `parent div` which is `div.insurance`  There are multiple `div.insurance` containers.  My issue is when using `thisButton.closest('.insurance').find(".attachmentCont");` it always focuses on the `.attachmentCont` div that was first selected.  So if I selected section 1, the image populates.  If I select section 2, section 1 still gets that image when the `div.attachmentCont` within section 2 should of gotten the `append()` too.

Suggestions or Thoughts?

**HTML EXAMPLE:**

```
<div class="notes-section insurance">
    <span><b>General </b></span><textarea style="width:97%;" rows="5" cols="50" class="insurance-description fields contractor_insurance_description" placeholder="...."></textarea>
    <input type="date" class="expiration-date" placeholder="Expiration Date">
    <br>
   <span>Your</span>
    <div class="attachmentCont">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" class="upload_image_button" value="Attach Documents" style="width:150px;">
</div>
```

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: So, you need the button to get a handle to the ".attachmentCont" element above it. But instead your code gets the one from another container sometimes. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: But one major point,  It always gets the handle on the first container it comes in contact with.  After that it will always stay on the container that was initially selected.  I've check the button to make sure its a different button and that is working correctly the place where it falters is when selecting for the `attachmentCont`

Answer (score 0):

Here was the issue:

My blindness did not see that the function that contains the `selected` button was not in any way associated with the function that `appended` the data.  Because of this all I had to do was move my `var thisButton` outside into the parent class.

Thank you everyone for you're time.

**Solutions:**

```
var thisButton

$('.upload_image_button').on('click', function( event ){
      thisButton = $(event.target);
      event.preventDefault();
});
....
function...({
      var appendThis = thisButton.closest('.insurance').find(".attachmentCont");
      appendThis.append('<div class="singleImg"><img src="'+attachment.url+'" width="100px"/><input type="hidden" class="fileURL" value="'+attachment.id+'"/><span class="removeImg remove"> X </span></div>');
      $(".removeImg").bind('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove(); 
      });
});
```